# GRUB settings do not persist

Tags: 14.04, grub2

I'm trying to make some fairly basic changes to a Ubuntu 14.04 install's boot behavior.  Specifically, I want the default operating system launched automatically (NOTE: I don't care whether or now the GRUB menu appears for a few seconds before booting into the default OS).  I get the desired behavior the next time I boot by editing the /etc/default/grub file and running update-grub.  However, things a back to bad on subsequent boots.

The following work around suffers from the same issue for me: https://gist.github.com/LeahCim/9332432

Before I start digging around the grub.d scripts to band-aid a solution, I wondered if anyone has had recent luck with this issue.

Answer (score 0):

Grub OS prober script will check if `timeout` is 0, and if other OS is present, will force `timeout=10`.

You can edit, as `sudo`, `/etc/grub.d/30_os-prober` file and comment these lines (close to line 36):

```
if [ "\${timeout}" = 0 ]; then
  set timeout=10
fi
```

Comment using `#` so they'll be like this:

```
#if [ "\${timeout}" = 0 ]; then
#  set timeout=10
#fi
```

Save it and close it.

Now you can run `sudo update-grub` and your `timeout=0` will be respected.